# Chromeless - can not click input submit button

Tags: javascript, html, chromeless

I am trying with chromeless to click on a submit button whose code is:

```
<input value="Submit" onclick="normal_upload()" id="submitbutton" type="button">
```

I have tried

```
const screenshot = await chromeless
        .click('input#submitbutton')
```

and

```
const screenshot = await chromeless
        .click('#submitbutton')
```

and

```
const screenshot = await chromeless
        .click('input[value="Submit"]')
```

but none of these seem to work (nothing happens, and no error message).

What could be blocking the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some luck, setting the `scrollBeforeClick` option to `true` in the [Chromeless constructor options](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless/blob/master/docs/api.md#chromeless-constructor-options) may solve the problem. If that does not help, or if it breaks something else, it might be worth trying to use the `.scrollToElement()` method to scroll to an element located some distance *below* the element that needs to be clicked. (It seems that scrolling is sometimes a few lines short of the necessary amount.)

Comment: scrollBeforeClick broke something else, but .scrollToElement worked (to an element *above* my button, scrolling to the button itself or an element below didn't work). But I thought chromeless was supposed to work headless too? Why would I have to care about scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes you need to `.scrollToElement('input#submitbutton')` for clicks to work.

Comment: not working for me. The scroll works though, so it's really not a problem of finding the selector, just clicking on it :(

Comment: If nothing helps, google for “webdriver” in combination with “Node.js” for systems based on the currently more reliable https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/ API.